# Data shown as being inserted when it's not in Visual Studio 2010 and MS Access

Tags: vb.net, connection

I have created a database in MS Access 2007 and a front end in Visual Studio 2010. The code is as follows:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form3
    Public connstring As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Course_Data.accdb;persist security info=false"
    Dim cn As New OleDbConnection
    'Dim cn As New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.Course_DataConnectionString)


    Private Sub Label14_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Label14.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try
            Dim sqlquery As String = "insert into Participant_info values('" & TextBox1.Text & "','" & TextBox2.Text & "','" & TextBox3.Text & "','" & TextBox4.Text & "','" & TextBox5.Text & "','" & TextBox6.Text & "','" & TextBox7.Text & "','" & TextBox8.Text & "','" & TextBox9.Text & "','" & TextBox10.Text & "','" & TextBox11.Text & "','" & TextBox12.Text & "','" & TextBox13.Text & "','" & TextBox14.Text & "','" & TextBox15.Text & "', '" & TextBox16.Text & "')"
            Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
            With cmd
                .CommandText = sqlquery
                .Connection = cn
                .ExecuteNonQuery()

            End With



            MsgBox("Details Inserted")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try




    End Sub

    Private Sub Form3_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        cn.ConnectionString = connstring
        If cn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            MsgBox("open")
        Else
            MsgBox("close")
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button6_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
        cn.ConnectionString = connstring
        cn.Open()
        TextBox17.Text = ("Connected")
    End Sub
End Class
```

It shows a message as data being inserted, but the data is not there in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes `Data Source=|DataDirectory|\...` is problematic when debugging. Please bear on mind that you'll have another database in `\bin\debug` at your project folder when you are debugging your code. Probably you're updating the records in this database instead the original one.

Try to set an absolute path and check if the records are being updated.

Also, **your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection**. You should build your `OleDbCommand` as follows:

```
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("insert into Participant_info values('?','?','?',······)", cn)

cmd.Parameters.Add(TextBox1.Text)
cmd.Parameters.Add(TextBox2.Text)
cmd.Parameters.Add(TextBox3.Text)
...
...
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
cn.close()
```